# Save browser output to xml file in php

Tags: php, xml, save, output

I want to save the below link's output to file.xml but it is not working for me. It just displays the output on another browser.

```
$url = 'http://www.forexwire.com/feed/full?username=alumfx&password=T7M9Exb4';
$fp = fopen (dirname(__FILE__). '/file.xml', 'w+');
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$ch->save('file.xml');
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: `$ch->save` what is it? Curl_init returns handle to curl resource not an object that has save method.

Answer (score 0):

By default CURL's exec function returns the result as standard output. You need to add this to make it return the result as a string:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

then just save it into a variable

```
$output = curl_exec($ch);
//do whatever with the $output
```

So that the complete code snippet can look like this:

```
$ch = curl_init('http://www.forexwire.com/feed/full?username=alumfx&password=T7M9Exb4'); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);
$output = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);
file_put_contents('path/to/file', $output);
```

Comment: with this I could able to display only part of the data and not entire data.

Comment: sorry, not sure i understood what you mean by "part of the data". this code fetches the whole page and instead of printing to the standard output returns it as a string. nothing more changes. by the way check the update to my answer, i add the complete code snippet with page retrieval and saving.